# Prometheus query per day not in 24h "buckets"

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics

I have a prometheus instance with grafana as UI and I want to have a graph that sums a rate of a gauge.

Right now I have something like:

```
sum(rate(myNiceMetric[1d])*60*60*24) by (result,component)
```

But the problem is that the rate time window covers the last 24h, but to have stable numbers I need it to be by day (00:00-24:00)

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the time range of the dashboard:

```
sum(rate(myNiceMetric[$__range])*$__range_s) by (result,component)
```

The panel will adjust automatically to the chosen time range (ex: last 24 hours, Yesterday, Today so far, Previous week, etc).

More info in the Grafana documentation [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/prometheus/).

Comment: No that doesn't help, I still want to have multiple days in the chart, but the grouping should be done at the day level

Comment: What have you done to show the graph grouped by the day?

Comment: Right now I'm using 24h windows for sum(rate(...)), but this is not a day grouping because when you query the data at 10AM, it will be to 10AM the prior day for all "days", this is bad when people try to have reliable numbers for their reports. That's why I'd like to have 0:00AM to 12:00PM per day

Comment: @PatrickCornelissen were you able to figure out a solution for this issue? I am also facing a similar problem

Comment: We gave up. More important things to tackle. But when you find a solution it would be interesting though.